# convert observable<object> to observable<task[]>

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

```
return  this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/tasks');

//Returns Observable<Object>, but I want it to return or convert into Observable<Task[]>.
```

Task is just an interface that matches the JSON object from the /tasks endpoint.

Comment: Are you using the `HttpModule` or the `HttpClientModule`?

Comment: HttpClientModule

Comment: Then @funkizer's answer below is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using HttpClient:

```
return this.http.get<Task[]>('http://localhost:3000/tasks');
```